# creating a new list and fill it based on the values of a pandas Series

Tags: python, list, pandas, series

I am trying to create a for loop that iterates through a pandas Series, `ageNew`, that fills a list, `label` , based on the contents of the pandas Series.

This is the code that I have which outputs errors:

In:

```
for i in ageNew.items():
    if ageNew[i] <= 100:
        val = 0
    else:
        val = 1
    label.append(val)
```

Out:

```
KeyError: (0, 218)
```

Comment: `for k,v in age_new.items()` **don't use camalCase**

Comment: You can use [`.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) instead of [`.items()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.items.html): `for i in ageNew.values:`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use vector operations instead of loops for efficiency and brevity

```
label = (age_new > 100).astype(int).tolist()
```

Comment: More performant version: `(age_new.values > 100).astype(int).tolist()`

Comment: oh that is cool, just out of curiosity, how would a vector operation work for a non-binary value, i.e. label can equal 0,1, or 2. Would it be like this: `((age_new <= 42) && (age_new > 7)).astype(int).tolist()`

Comment: almost! use the bit-wise `and` operator `&` instead of `&&`. `&&` is not a valid python operator. Similarly, the bit-wise `or` operator is `|` and not `||`

Answer (score 1):

when you use `item()` you need to pass two arguments in for statment example:

```
for k,v in dct.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .values instead of .items() to get just the value:

```
for v in dct.values:
    if v <= 100:
        ...
```

Comment: that outputs `KeyError: 218`

Comment: what if you do: `if i <= 100` ?

Comment: `values` is not a function of a pandas Series. This is not a dictionary.